# Javascript Get Data from another page and return value outside of $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from another page, but can't pass this data using this code.

```
$("#doctorAddModalBtn").on('click', function()
{
    alert(RandomCode());   
});

function RandomCode()
{
    pageLink = 'RandomCodeGenerate.php';

    $.get(pageLink, function(result){
        return result;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: you are not returning anything from function. A return inside the callback does not return to outer function....and ajax is **asynchronous**

Comment: Here i can access the value in $.get , but can't access value outside of this. how i can i access the value

Comment: consume the data in the callback